# How to get time in Indian Time zone?

Tags: php, time, timezone

For You tube API we are setting start Schedule time and End time In

```
"2015-08-28T00:00:00.000Z"
```

This format the Z- is representing the zulu (GMT-7) time zone. I need to pass the time with Indian time zone code (GMT+5:30).

What's the code I need to put for Indian timezone representation?

Comment: Change your tags accordingly !

Comment: See the [PHP Timezone Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.indian.php)

Comment: `Z` is GMT+0, not -7.

Answer (score 22):

Just set the default time zone to your Local time zone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");   //India time (GMT+5:30)
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 13):

for PHP, timezone is

> 'Asia/Kolkata'

you can set the timezone by `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`

check  [PHP: Asia Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) for other timezones in Asia.

Answer (score 7):

Just set the default time zone to your Local time zone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");   //India time (GMT+5:30)
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
date.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

In php.ini file in PHP directory.

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) for Asian timezones.

Answer (score 2):

```
[PHP]
;
; php.ini file changes
;
; This works too
;date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta
;
date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"   Best Solution, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just set the default time zone to your Local time zone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");   //India time (GMT+5:30)
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```

For India You Can Use : 'Asia/Kolkata',

Here is list of supported time zone in Asia
[Asia](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)
List of All Time zones
[All Time Zones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s a');
?>
```

it will return following output :
02-12-2021 06:02:41 pm